# Is there an instrument to separate a beam of mixed charged particle into its components (kaons, electrons, positrons...)?

Tags: particle-physics, elementary-particles

Is there a method to separate a beam of particles into its constituents such as electrons, muons and kaons? Is there a method to separate a mixed beam of particles into pure beams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you start with a beam of uniform kinetic energy then any magnetic field does exactly that. As a practical matter you use a fairly strong magnet to do it in a reasonable space.

The problem is that you don't generally have a beam of mixed particles with uniform energy. But you do see this technique used in the CEBAF accelerator at Jefferson lab. The electron beam recirculates a few times in the main ring, and on the approach to the bends at the end of the race-track the beam is separated into sub beams that have been through 0, 1, 2, 3, or 4 times (because these beams have essentially the same speed ($c - \epsilon$), but different momentums) already and each sub-beam is bent separately then recombined as they head back into the straight.

In principle you could run the beam through a velocity separator first, but you'll throw a lot a stuff away.

Comment: "Assuming you start with a beam of uniform kinetic energy then any magnetic field does exactly that. As a practical matter you use a fairly strong magnet to do it in a reasonable space." So this is a commonly used method?

Comment: And also what is the widely used term for "particle separator" for further research?

Comment: There is no widely used term. The situation you are envisioning just doesn't come up. Magnetic fields used to separate particles by their charge:momentum ratios are called "momentum analyzers" or "spectrometers" in various contexts.

Answer (score 1):

For a complicated beam, of particles created by hitting a target and then creating secondary beams for experiments look at this T9 link of the [T9 beam](https://beamline-for-schools.web.cern.ch/sites/beamline-for-schools.web.cern.ch/files/BL4S-Examples_0.pdf) at CERN. Example 7.

You will see that separation to definite particles needs extra instrumentation to identify the particle content of the beam. If you really want more information have a look [at this article](https://indico.cern.ch/event/115334/contributions/67588/attachments/1249442/1841487/Efthymiopoulos.pdf).